# What is the minumun version to run firebase in a flutter project for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

I think that I'm giving some errors on my firebase flutter app on iOS and Android becouse it's running on low gamma of cellphones. Could you please tell me what's the minimun requirements to add firebase to a flutter project for both platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ios:

> Make sure that your project meets these requirements:

1. Your project must target iOS 8 or later.
2. Swift projects must use Swift 3.0 or later.

Android:

> By default, Flutter supports Android SDK v16 (Jelly Bean, released 2012), but multidex doesn't really work with Jelly Bean (though, it's possible). Configuring Jelly Bean to work is beyond the scope of this codelab, so we'll change the minimum target SDK version from v16 to v21 (Lollipop, released 2014)

Therefore in android use `minSdkVersion 21`

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#3

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup